# Getting privileges error when trying to get users from my own telegram channel (Telethon API)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'am using [Telethon API](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) and getting a privilege error in the function *GetParticipantsRequest* when I try to get the users inside my own telegram **channel**, in which I'am Admin.

```
telethon.errors.rpc_error_list.ChatAdminRequiredError: (ChatAdminRequiredError(...), 'Chat admin privileges are required to do that in the specified chat (for e
xample, to send a message in a channel which is not yours)')
```

Makes no sense because when I do the same code routine with a telegram **group** of mine, it works like a charm.

Here goes the routine:

```
def getUserNames(channel):
offset = 0
limit = 100
all_participants = []
selected_participants = []
channel = client(ResolveUsernameRequest(channel))
channel = InputChannel(channel.chats[0].id, channel.chats[0].access_hash)       

while True:
    participants = client(
        GetParticipantsRequest(channel, ChannelParticipantsSearch(''), offset, limit, 0)
    )
    if not participants.users:
        break
    all_participants.extend(participants.users)
    offset += len(participants.users)

if len(all_participants):
    for x in all_participants:
        if x.username: selected_participants.append(x.username)
    print (selected_participants)
    return selected_participants
else:
    return -1
```

Is there something I'am missing here?